# AJAX first attempt json data element not changing

Tags: ajax, custom-data-attribute

Hi I have my first AJAX JSON working and it returns C5:3; at the moment for development and displays this in a div, a img tag should be replaced from a off.png to a on.png but this isn't happening.  Would appreciate if anyone could through some light on this??  here is my code

```
          $("button.checkStatus").click(function(){
          //This Ajax checks the current on/off status of the passed X10 code
          $('img.checkStatus').each(function(i, obj) {
          $x10Device = $(this).data("x10");
          var postData = "url=http://local/tenHsServer/tenHsServer.aspx?t=ab&   
           f=DeviceStatus&d=" + $x10Device ;
           $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   dataType: "json",
                   data: postData,
                   beforeSend: function(x) {
                   if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                   x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                   }
              },
            url: 'urlencodeJson.php',
            success: function(data) {
            // 'data' is a JSON object which we can access directly.
           // Evaluate the data.success member and do something appropriate...
          if (data.success == true){
              $('#section1').html(data.message);
              $("X10").data('src','lightbulbon.png');
          }
          else{
               $('#section2').html(data.message);
               $("X10").data('src','lightbulbon.png');
           }
           }
           });
```

The HTML

```
 <img src="lightbulboff.png" class="checkStatus" data-x10="C5">
 <img src="lightbulboff.png" class="checkStatus" data-x10="C6">
 <img src="lightbulboff.png" class="checkStatus" data-x10="C7">
 <button class="checkStatus">Device Status Check</button>
 <div id="section1"></div>
 <div id="section2"></div>
```

This is driving me crazy!!! every way tried over the last 2 days hit a brick wall would be great if I could crack it!!!

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could change a couple of things to make it works, first of all change the success part inside your ajax request:

```
 $("X10").data('src','lightbulbon.png');
```

this wont lead you anywhere, since you're addressing nothing, insted save you current object in a variable and change it (or use the $(this) context where this is your current image object) :

```
$(this).attr('src','lightbulbon.png');
```

another little thing is how you set up the call, while it's not wrong, doing :

```
    $x10Device = $(this).data("x10");


 var postData = "url=http://local/tenHsServer/tenHsServer.aspx?t=ab&   
       f=DeviceStatus&d=" + $x10Device ;
```

could be a little redundant and can lead to easy error while you setup a post request, just rewrite it like an array :

```
data: {url : 'http://local/tenHsServer/tenHsServer.aspx?t=ab', 
                           f : 'DeviceStatus', 
                           d: $(this).data("x10") }
```

the whole function should be like :

```
     $("button.checkStatus").click(function(){
                  $('img.checkStatus').each(function(i, obj) {
var element = $(this);
                   $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: 'urlencodeJson.php',
                       dataType: "json",
                       data: { url : 'http://local/tenHsServer/tenHsServer.aspx?t=ab', 
                               f : 'DeviceStatus', 
                               d: $(this).data("x10") },
                       beforeSend: function(x) {
                           if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                           x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                           },
                       success: function(data) {
                          if (data.success == true){
                              $('#section1').html(data.message);
                              element.attr('src','lightbulbon.png');
                          }
                          else{
                               $('#section2').html(data.message);
                               element.attr('src','lightbulbon.png');
                           }
                       }
                   }); 
                  });
            });
```

Comment: Thanks! but when the code gets to the IF section $(this) has become the AJAX object containing all the setting to make the call to the PHP file :(

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  much appreciated !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  going to take a break and then look at turnig sorting out my ajax curl php file to returning the JSON object